# The etymology of February

Tags: french, middle-english, silent-letters

According to my dictionary, the word February originates directly from Middle English "Feverer" from Old French "Feverier" yet the Modern English word more closely resembles the original Latin spelling "februarius." So where did the "v" in the Middle English and Old French come from, and why was it discarded in our current pronunciation? Also, when and why was the "r" after "b" rendered silent?

Comment: The "r" after the "b" *isn't* silent, if you pronounce it correctly! FEB BREW ARY is how I've pronounced it since about the 3rd grade.

Comment: Did you actually search "February Etymology" and come up lacking in results?

Comment: A _b_->_v_ shift is not uncommon. In modern Greek, the _beta_ is actually pronounced as a _v_.

Comment: @oerkelens This one goes the other way, though. (At least after the French version.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: also not uncommon, in Spanish the _v_ gets pronounced like a _b_ by some speakers. The two are just incredibly close.

Comment: @oerkelens Spanish is a somewhat different matter, since it only has one phoneme, whether you want to call that /b/ or /v/. And neither development has taken place in English, where /b/ and /v/ have remained separate throughout history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Etymonline gives information about what is known about the etymology of February.
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=february&searchmode=none

As to the change from b to v there is nothing astonishing about this. The articulation of b and v is very similar. When pronouncing b you produce a stop of the air stream by closing both lips. When producing v you weaken this closure. Often sounds are weakened to reduce articulation work.

If in spelling the b  was introduced again we may assume that is was the aim to latinize the spelling again and to show the connection with the Latin word februarius mensis.

Comment: You link mentions a "14c. respelling to conform to Latin", so I don't think we need to _assume_ too much about why the current version looks a lot like the Latin version :)

Comment: It escaped my notice. Will change my formulation.